# C++ Pre-compiled Headers: Two generated .gch are never identical for the same source file

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to understand why pre-compiled header objects for a system header file are never the same between two compiler calls if the source file didn't change.

I can show this behavior with this very simple test:

```
$ cat pch.hpp
#include <string.h>

$ g++ pch.hpp -o pch1.hpp.gch && g++ pch.hpp -o pch2.hpp.gch
$ cksum pch1.hpp.gch pch2.hpp.gch
285552444 3408816 pch1.hpp.gch
612212458 3408816 pch2.hpp.gch
```

I could replicate this in Windows 7 (GCC 5.3.0 with MSYS2), Mac OS X (GCC 6.1.0 from Homebrew) and Arch Linux (GCC 6.1.1).

Looking at the dependencies, I couldn't find any [predefined macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Predefined-Macros.html#Predefined-Macros) that could change the output between two consecutive compilations.

Comparing the generated files, some sequences of bytes are out of order (in the image, the string "pch.hpp" appears later in the file to the left) and some single bytes are different, even though the file sizes are the same.

[image: Hexdump comparison]

So does gcc really does not guarantee that the same PCH is generated each time or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe there's a timestamp.  Try generating files as fast as you can and see how many bytes change.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2005-02/msg00922.html

Comment: I'm curious as to what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks for the link @John, but the timestamp mentioned should be related to the modification time of compiler executable, which does not change between the two calls. And I couldn't find this timestamp in the current version of the `c-pch.c`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I'm trying to use ccache in a project that already uses a PCH but I can't use its "PCH sloppiness" setting because there are some important defines that can be changed. So I can't store the PCH in the cache, it needs to be always recompiled and generate an object with the same hash to get cache hits. But these objects are always different, so I get only misses.

Comment: Interesting. Well, I think you should ask the GCC mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differences are caused by ASLR. Disabling it leads to reproducible gchs:

```
# setarch $(uname -m) -R /usr/bin/c++ -x c++-header -include test.hxx -o test.hxx.gch -c test.hxx.cxx && md5sum test.hxx.gch
54486c6ffc08db87d4b58792dcb46091  test.hxx.gch
# setarch $(uname -m) -R /usr/bin/c++ -x c++-header -include test.hxx -o test.hxx.gch -c test.hxx.cxx && md5sum test.hxx.gch
54486c6ffc08db87d4b58792dcb46091  test.hxx.gch
```

However, ASLR is generally a good thing and disabling it is not a real solution. This is also being discussed [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92717).